# How to chain the groups in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

[This is the layout I am going to do using Constraint Layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH5oq.png)

I want to create the above layout without any Nesting of Views, which is one of the advantages of using Constraint Layout.

It is a simple layout. But i wish to add vertical chaining to the layout.

If i add vertical chaining, each and every view will be spread. But my condition is that the Text View and the View(Horizontal line) should be together, as a group.

And i need to chain that group. I tried the following way:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.Settings">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/canc_pol"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarLayout" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicy" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup"
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicyGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="cancelPolicy,cancelPolicyLine" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCond"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/t_and_c"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicyLine" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCondLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCond" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="termsAndCond,termsAndCondLine"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup"
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCondGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/priv_pol"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCondLine" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicy" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/aboutGroup"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="privatePolicy,privatePolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/about"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicyLine" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/aboutLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/about" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/aboutGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineBottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="about,aboutLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But only the groups were chained, the views still remained the same.
[This is What i got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w16PX.png)
 I would like to know weather we can chain groups of views without nesting of layouts.

Comment: What is the problem? In your links you have two same view representation. Do you have issue with contraining Groups, Of linked Views?

Comment: Well i need to distribute the views(the set of Text View and Horizontal Line) in the layout equally. I just now found out a solution. I'll post it. Kindly correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, this worked out for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.Settings">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/canc_pol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cancelPolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cancelPolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicy" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicyGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="cancelPolicy,cancelPolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCond"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/t_and_c"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/termsAndCondLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCondLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCond" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCondGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="termsAndCond,termsAndCondLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicyGroup" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/priv_pol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/privatePolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicy" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicyGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="privatePolicy,privatePolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/aboutGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="@string/about"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/aboutLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/aboutGroup"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/aboutLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/aboutGroup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/about" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/aboutGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="about,aboutLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineBottom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just made the groups to spread throughout the layout by giving height as 0 and positioned my views within those groups. 
And i got this:[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx732.png)

For anyone trying to spread the views in the entire screen, just make the Vertical Guideline to have `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"`

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="canc_pol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancelPolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbarLayout" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cancelPolicy" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/cancelPolicyGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="cancelPolicy,cancelPolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbarLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCond"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="t_and_c"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/termsAndCondLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/termsAndCondGroup" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCondLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/termsAndCond" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/termsAndCondGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="termsAndCond,termsAndCondLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancelPolicyGroup" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="priv_pol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/privatePolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/privatePolicyGroup" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicyLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/privatePolicy" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/privatePolicyGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="privatePolicy,privatePolicyLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/aboutGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/termsAndCondGroup" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="about"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/aboutLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aboutGroup" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/aboutLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about" />

    <android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/aboutGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="about,aboutLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineBottom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/privatePolicyGroup" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output like this...

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have also found a solution, i'll post below, If there are any corrections, let me know.